# Windows 10 errors in WinPE environment for Windows Updates

Tags: windows-10, bsod, windows-update

I built a new PC and installed Windows 10 Professional 64-bit. The hardware and hard drives were new, no OS was on the system prior. The Windows 10 installation disc had the original Windows 10 build from August 2015.

1. When Windows Update tried to install the November 2015 update, it would reboot into the black-backgrounded WinPE environment, get between 20-60% complete (I tried this multiple times, even with all USB devices removed), then show the `CLOCK_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT` error every time.

   To fix this, I used the Media Creation Tool, which made a new Windows 10 disc which applied the November 2015 update during installation. I installed this after formatting the drive, so once again, clean installation.
2. Now with the clean Windows 10 Pro 64, with the November 2015 update, I was able to install GPU drivers, all the subsequent updates (until yesterday's Anniversary Update).

   I have been able to play DOOM and Fallout 4 for hours, no issues whatsoever.
3. I tried to install the August 2016 Anniversary Update last night.

   It downloads, reboots into the WinPE environment, and fails after ~20% with the super informative `WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR` message. It when reboots back into Windows 10, without the update applied. Everything still works, Fallout, Doom, Steam, Chrome, Dropbox, etc.

How do I get around what seems to be a recurring WinPE error?

- The clock error in #1 seems to come from a hardware issue according to what I've found online.
- The uncorrectable error in #2 seems to also be hardware-related, notably from overclocking, according to what I have been able to find so far, which I am not doing.

  Since I can play Fallout 4 on Ultra settings, I cannot accept that this is a hardware issue. Furthermore, I am not overclocking my hardware (CPU, GPU, RAM) in any way.

What could be the problem, and how do I fix this?

It just seems that the WinPE environment is just an example of very poor programming, since it's not just me who have been experiencing this, from what I can tell.

[Machine specs](http://pcpartpicker.com/user/CeruleanBlue/builds/#view=vY4CmG):

- Intel I7 CPU 6700K Skylake
- ASRock Fatality Z170, EFI firmware updated to latest version
- NVidia GeForce 1080
- Samsung 950 Pro M.2 drive
- Samsung 850 Pro SSD
- 32 GB RAM

**Update 11 August 2016**:

- I have tried installing on a different SSD, same crash during Anniversary Update.
- I replaced the CPU with the identical model, Skylake 6700K. Both old and new CPUs passed the Intel Diagnostic Tool, and the new CPU still had the crash.
- I have tried different memory combinations, no change. Memory does pass Memtest.
- Windows reset and three full re-installs of Windows 10 Pro haven't fixed the issue.
- I've tried the update with the GPU removed and using the embedded Intel Graphics, no improvement.
- I've tried using Ethernet, and removed the USB WiFi adapter, no improvement.
- I've made new ISO's with the Media Creation Tool, but it isn't making ISO's with the Anniversary Update included, only with updates until July 2016 (even this week, one week after the Anniversary Update).
- Also I noticed that when it crashes, no dumps are ever created despite being configured to do so.

I don't so much care about the Anniversary Update, but I'm afraid future software may depend on the new build. Already I had this issue where the Nvidia drivers wouldn't install until the November 2015 update was installed. What future software, updates, and security patches will be missed if the Anniversary Update is not installed?

Comment: share all dmps from C:\Windows\minidump

Comment: That directory doesn't exist, but under System Properties -> Advanced -> Settings -> System failure, it is set to create a dump in %SystemRoot%\MEMORY.DMP, but I think that's different...

Comment: I just tried to use the Media Creation Tool and selected "Upgrade this Computer". It again had the Clock WatchDog Timeout error in #1. When it came back, it said: "The installation failed in the SAFE_OS phase with an error during INSTALL_RECOVERY_ENVIRONMENT operation".

Comment: Intel Processor Diagnostic Tool v3.0.0.25.W.MP says the processor passed all tests.

Comment: ok, if you get crashes during setup, look for a  setupmem.dmp here: :\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\. also share the complete folder, so that I can also look at the logs

Comment: Panther doesn't have a .dmp file, but here's the contents shared via Dropbox https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ci3ghi3wsnpxrc9/AACXfdMIB0asY4MdIPILPp0Fa?dl=0

Comment: Any comments @magicandre1981? Also, I replaced the CPU just in case, still crashes during Anniversary Update installation. This new CPU and old both pass Intel's Processor Diagnostic Tool.

Comment: I was able to get the Anniversary Update to install by downloading and installing the Windows Insider Preview, which coincidentally was the same build version as the Anniv. Update. This meant I had to do a clean install. But what about the next update?? Will I have the same problems? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: I noticed that the Windows Insider DVD installer partitioned the drive differently, and with GPT instead of MBR. So perhaps that was the problem.

Comment: GPT is for UEFI boot and MBR for old BIOS boot.